# Search by tags and title in mysql

Tags: mysql, search

I want to search in my db programs and news by title or tags I have this code in mysql:

```
 Select * 
   from promociones,promocion_tag,programa_tag,tags,programas 
  WHERE tags.nombre='STH' 
    AND tags.id=programa_tag.id_tag 
    AND programa_tag.id_programa=programas.id
     OR tags.nombre='STH' 
    AND tags.id=promocion_tag.id_tag 
    AND promocion_tag.id_promocion=promociones.id  
     OR promociones.titulo LIKE "%STH%" 
     OR programas.titulo LIKE "%STH%"
```

You see any error? Because its return something wrong, the same row many times..

---

Tables (important columns):
Programas
-ID
-Titulo

Promociones
-ID
-Titulo

-Tags
-ID
-Nombre

Programa_tag
-id_tag
-programa_tag

Promocion_tag
-id_tag
-promocion_tag

Comment: Add joins.  Put parenthesis around criteria that should be separated by `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parentheses due to the precedence of `AND` then `OR`. Using explicit `JOIN` syntax would also be helpful.

```
...
AND tags.id=programa_tag.id_tag 
AND (programa_tag.id_programa=programas.id
 OR tags.nombre='STH')
AND tags.id=promocion_tag.id_tag 
AND (promocion_tag.id_promocion=promociones.id  
 OR promociones.titulo LIKE "%STH%" 
 OR programas.titulo LIKE "%STH%")
```

[See the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

Answer (score 0):

For better readability (and easier debugging) I've rephrased your SELECT to use JOINS (plus I added parenthesis around the OR expression:

```
SELECT * FROM tags
JOIN programa_tag ON tags.id=programa_tag.id_tag 
JOIN programas ON programa_tag.id_programa=programas.id 
JOIN promocion_tag ON promocion_tag.id_tag = tags.id
JOIN promociones ON promociones.id = promocion_tag.id_promocion
WHERE tags.nombre='STH' AND 
(promociones.titulo LIKE "%STH%" OR programas.titulo LIKE "%STH%")
```

Without further knowledge about your database I can only guess if the JOINs should actually be LEFT JOINS or not. Also, this SELECT might actually require a UNION, but you'd need to give more details to make that call.

Comment: Also, your `LIKE '%STH%' search clauses are going to be absurdly slow.

Comment: @Ollie Jones agreed. MySQL will not be able to use any indexes when you are matching a string that starts with a wildcard. So doing a `LIKE "%WHATEVER"` is bad for performance.

Comment: @Diego_sf93. What recommend? Words. Describe the relationships between objects in your database. Describe what you're trying to accomplish. Describe what you've tried, and how that failed. The better your question is, the better the answers are going to be.

Comment: Well, I want a search function which search by tags that are representate by 1 table that contains the program id and the tag id like foreign key of each columns, same to news table..
And also search by the title of the program or the new.. understand?

And thats code is try to be the serch sql statement